# Why is Sphinx auto-documentation causing python-dotenv problems?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-dotenv

I'm working with [sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) to document a python project, but its not integrating well with python-dotenv. When running `.\make`, I'll get a warning that boils down to:

```
logging.getLogger(config['APP_NAME'])

KeyError: 'APP_NAME'
```

This led me to see if my app configuration (which uses dotenv) is working properly. I'm using the following structure to persist the configuration throughout the project:

```py
from dotenv import dotenv_values
config = {
    **dotenv_values('.env.example'),
    **dotenv_values('.env'),
}

for key, val in config.items():
    try:
        if val in ['True', 'False']:
            config[key] = bool(val == 'True')
        else:
            config[key] = float(val)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

I tried printing out the dotenv values, and am getting empty dictionaries. This leads me to believe that sphinx is somehow messing with imports?

The relevant file structure is as follows:

```
.
└── Project/
    ├── docs/
    │   ├── _build/
    │   │   └── html
    │   └── make.bat
    │   └── conf.py
    ├── src/
    │   └── main/
    │       ├── other files/directories
    │       └── app_config.py
    ├── .env
    └── .env.example
```

I normally wouldn't be too concerned about a warning, but any files that use the configuration won't be properly documented. The sphinx docs don't discuss any weird specifics required for using environment variables, and I can't find anything else with a similar problem.
In case its relevant, here's my conf.py file:

```
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# For the full list of built-in configuration values, see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#project-information
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#general-configuration

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
    'myst_parser'
]

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']



# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-html-output

html_theme = 'furo'
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

When printing `os.getcwd()`  it'll say it's in the /docs directory (after running .\make html). I tried fixing this by using `os.chdir('..')` to put me in the root directory, but it did nothing.

I've tried running `docs\make.bat html`  to see if it was the location from which make was being run that was affecting it, but still no change.

An obvious solution here is to just make a try/except block to manage when sphinx is building the project, but I want to understand why this is happening instead of using a hack solution.

The app runs normally, so is there some reason Sphinx would be causing this problem?